# How to have Counts in a Join query

Tags: sql, join, count

I have to create a join between two tables on a column and display the counts of the fields on  which they are joined

For example here '**business**' is my key on which i want to join.

The first query is

```
select 
    [business], count(*) as total from dimhexpand group by [business]
```

and I get a result as:

```
DA  54100

Dual    6909

ECM 1508

Flex    15481
```

Another query is :

```
select business, count (*) from LODG
group by business order by business
```

the result of the query is :

```
DA  100

Dual    909

ECM 508

Flex    15481
```

I want to return the data by joining these two tables to show something like

```
**dimhexpand.business dimhexpand.count LODG.Count**
DA          54100       100 

Dual            6909        909

ECM         1508        508

Flex            15481       151481
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can JOIN the two tables on the `business` column:

```
select d.business, 
  count(d.business) as dimCount,
  l.lodgCount
from dimhexpand d
left join
(
  select business, count (*) lodgCount
  from LODG 
  group by business 
) l
  on d.business = l.business
group by d.business;
```

If you might have different `business` values in each table, then you can use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` between both queries, similar to this:

```
select coalesce(d.business, l.business),
  coalesce(d.dimCount, 0) dimCount,
  coalesce(l.lodgCount, 0) lodgCount
from
(
  select business, count(*) as dimCount 
  from dimhexpand 
  group by business
) d
full outer join
(
  select business, count (*) lodgCount
  from LODG 
  group by business 
) l
  on d.business = l.business
```

Comment: Thanks It works. But can we have the same thing when we deal with 3 tables, I was trying but was getting stuck while joining one more table with the same structure.

Comment: @BhaskarMishra If you have another question, then I suggest post a new question with those details. :)  Then you will get a fresh pair of eyes to help out.

Answer (score 0):

Some questions require answering to provide an accurate answer.  Can you have business in dimhexpand and not in LODG or vice versa?
The subquery answer provided above will work if you will always have a one to one on business.  if not, you will lose values from either table if not fully joined.
If you can have business unique to either table, can you work with memory tables?

```
Declare @tblDimhExpand TABLE (
    business varchar(50) null, 
    CountDimHExpand int null
    )
Declare @tblLoDG TABLE (
    business varchar(50) null, 
    CountLodG int null
    )

Insert into @tblDimhExpand select business, count(*) from DimhExpand Group By Business

Insert into @tblLoDG select business, count(*) from LODG Group By Business

Select coalesce(dim.business, lodg.business) as Business, dim.countDimhExpand, lodg.countlodg
    From @tblDimhExpand dim
    FULL JOIN @tblLodG lodg on dim.Business = lodg.Business
```

This will return all business records from both tables regardless of whether they are present on the other table, and will join the results when present in both, and give NULL for the table missing that value when they are present in only one.

Comment: Great, this works. Thanks a Lot. Now I need to figure out which query takes more time :-).